# Azure B2C: Query users based on otherMails and/or signInNames.emailAddress fields

Tags: email, odata, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

So my task is to query user data based on user's email. During the development we used standard policies and later custom policies to register customers. I made a query to find users based on *otherMails* field:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,id,createdDateTime,surName,givenName,otherMails&$filter=startswith(otherMails,'viktor')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,id,createdDateTime,surName,givenName,otherMails&$filter=startswith(otherMails,%27viktor%27))

But I was wondering how to find users who's email is not set in *otherMails* but *signInNames.emailAddress*? As far as I know this field is populated if a customer is registered via Standard policy and *otherMails* in case of using custom policies. Any idea how to get address this field (*signInNames.emailAddress*) in any oData query?

Ty!

Comment: Hi, any update here? If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[`signInNames.emailAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes#azure-ad-user-resource-type) is included in [`identities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/objectidentity?view=graph-rest-1.0).

[image]

**Note:** `identities` supports `$filter` (`eq`) only where the `signInType` is not `userPrincipalName`. So you couldn't use `startswith` for identities.

```
$filter=identities/any(id:id/issuer eq 'contoso.onmicrosoft.com' and id/issuerAssignedId eq 'viktor@xxx.com')
```

[image]

Comment: Ty Pamela! Just on thing here more: What about the social registrations? If I register with social provider (google, apple, fb) this issuerAssignedId has some random number like 3398465550205780.

Comment: This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes#identities-attribute) has explained about this situation. *"Federated identity - Also known as a social or enterprise accounts, the identity of the user is managed by a federated identity provider like Facebook, Microsoft, ADFS, or Salesforce." "federated, `issuerAssignedId` represents the federated account unique identifier"*